# GDAL dissolve algorithm give error on input layer geometry column

Tags: python, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to use GDAL dissolve algorithm, like the following code:

```
# Dissolve
alg_params = {
    'COMPUTE_AREA': True,
    'COMPUTE_STATISTICS': False,
    'COUNT_FEATURES': True,
    'EXPLODE_COLLECTIONS': True,
    'FIELD': 'Dissolve',
    'GEOMETRY': 'geometry',
    'INPUT': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
    'KEEP_ATTRIBUTES': True,
    'OPTIONS': '',
    'STATISTICS_ATTRIBUTE': '',
    'OUTPUT': parameters['Dissolved']
}
outputs['Dissolve'] = processing.run('gdal:dissolve', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
results['Dissolved'] = outputs['Dissolve']['OUTPUT']
```

However, this algorithm gives the following error message:

```
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry,*, COUNT(geometry) AS count,SUM(ST_Area(geometry)) AS area, ST_Perimeter(ST_Union(geometry)) AS perimeter FROM "INPUT" GROUP BY "Dissolve"): 
no such column: geometry
Process returned error code 1
```

How can I find the name of the geometry column of a polygon shapefile?

Comment: Is the input a shapefile or something else that is created from the shapefile? Looking at the row `'INPUT': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT']`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `'GEOMETRY': 'geom'` instead of `'GEOMETRY': 'geometry'`.

Different data providers may be using different geometry column name. You can try different names: `GEOM`, `GEOMETRY`, `the_geom` etc.

Comment: No, none of these terms are suitable for solving this problem.
However, I verify that the Processing History related to the execution of the GDAL's Dissolve algorithm from the Toolbox also presents the same error.
Does the problem occur because the Input Vector is a shapefile?

Comment: @MLourdes possible.